# Configuring the number of member examining committee on Approval sheet

Tags: memoir, thesis, automation

I know that there is already at least one question here on how to set up an approval sheet. However, the question I bring you now is slightly different, because the question itself regards on how to automate the number of members of the examining committee. Often, depending on the program to which the student is affiliated, the committee may consist of three, four, five, or more members. Thus, I would like to compose a code in which I could inform in the document preamble the following information: 1 - inform the number of members of the examining committee; 2 - enter the name of the first member; 3 - inform the title of the first member; 4 - inform the institution of the first member, and so on. Of course that items 2, 3, and 4 would be repeated as I informed the number of members present on the committee. Would it be possible to create such a code?

Below, I present a minimal example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\parindent0pt

\setSpacing{1.5}

\abnormalparskip{0.2\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}%
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule width 50mm \kern 
2.6pt}%

\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{20mm}{*}%
\setulmarginsandblock{30mm}{20mm}{*}%
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\setheaderspaces{20.0mm}{*}{*}%
\setmarginnotes{2.0mm}{16mm}{5.0mm}%
\setcolsepandrule{3.5mm}{0.15mm}
\setfootins{\bigskipamount}{\bigskipamount}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\newcommand{\committeemembernumber}[1]{#1}

\newcommand{\memberonename}[1]{\gdef\thememberonename{#1}}
\newcommand{\memberoneinstitute}[1]{\gdef\thememberoneinstitute{#1}}

\newcommand{\membertwoname}[1]{\gdef\themembertwoname{#1}}
\newcommand{\membertwoinstitute}[1]{\gdef\themembertwoinstitute{#1}}

\newcommand{\memberthreename}[1]{\gdef\thememberthreename{#1}}
\newcommand{\memberthreeinstitute}[1]{\gdef\thememberthreeinstitute{#1}}

\newcommand{\memberfourname}[1]{\gdef\thememberfourname{#1}}
\newcommand{\memberfourinstitute}[1]{\gdef\thememberfourinstitute{#1}}

\newcommand{\memberfivename}[1]{\gdef\thememberfivename{#1}}
\newcommand{\memberfiveinstitute}[1]{\gdef\thememberfiveinstitute{#1}}


\title{Approval sheet: an example for the LaTeX}
\author{Alexsandro Lucena Mota}
\date{2020}

%\committeemembernumber{3}

\memberonename{Prof.~MA. Sir Isaac Newton}
\memberoneinstitute{Trinity College -- University of Cambrigde}

\membertwoname{Prof.~PhD. Albert Einstein}
\membertwoinstitute{Institute for Advanced Study (IAS)}

\memberthreename{Prof. PhD. Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac}
\memberthreeinstitute{Florida State University}

\memberfourname{Prof. PhD. Richard Phillips Feynman}
\memberfourinstitute{California Institute of Technology -- Caltech}

\memberfivename{Prof. PhD. Murray Gell-Mann}
\memberfiveinstitute{California Institute of Technology -- Caltech}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        {\large \theauthor\par}
        
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        
        {\Large
            \begin{OnehalfSpace}%
                \bfseries\thetitle\par%
            \end{OnehalfSpace}%
    }

    \vspace{0.0cm}
    
    \end{center}
    \begin{flushright}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}%
            \begin{SingleSpacing}%     
                {\small Doctoral thesis presented at Postgraduate 
                Program in Physics of the Universidade Federal do 
                Maranhão as prerequisite to obtain the Doctoral 
                degree.}\par
            
                {\small {\bfseries Research line:} Topological 
                field theory with Lorentz symmetry breaking.}\par%
            \end{SingleSpacing}%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{flushright}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    Approval in: \rule[0.0cm]{3cm}{0.04cm}~ 
    \rule[0.0cm]{1cm}{0.04cm},~\thedate.\par
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{center}
        
        {\Large Examining  Committee}\par%
        
        \vspace{\baselineskip}  
        
        \begin{SingleSpacing}
                  
            \rule{12cm}{0.04cm}\par%
            \thememberonename\par%
            \thememberoneinstitute\par
                  
            \vspace{1.9\baselineskip}
            
            \rule{12cm}{0.04cm}\par
            \themembertwoname\par%
            \themembertwoinstitute\par
            
            \vspace{1.9\baselineskip}      
            
            \rule{12cm}{0.04cm}\par
            \thememberthreename\par
            \thememberthreeinstitute\par 
                 
            \vspace{1.9\baselineskip}  
            
            \rule{12cm}{0.04cm}\par
            \thememberfourname\par%
            \thememberfourinstitute\par   
                
            \vspace{1.9\baselineskip}      
              
            \rule{12cm}{0.04cm}\par
            \thememberfivename\par
            \thememberfiveinstitute\par
        \end{SingleSpacing}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```

This code provides the following pdf document:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. The basic idea is to have a single command:

```
\member{<name>}{<institute>}
```

This will automatically assign membership of the committee, and keep track of how many there are. Then each committee name/affiliation is given a unique name using the counter that keeps track of the members. This is done using the `\csgdef` wrapper for `\csname ... \endcsname` provided by the `etoolbox` package. We then use that counter and a loop (using the `pgffor` package) to produce the right number of member lines (limited of course by the amount of space you have on the page.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\parindent0pt

\setSpacing{1.5}

\abnormalparskip{0.2\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5cm}%
\renewcommand*{\footnoterule}{\kern -3pt \hrule width 50mm \kern 
2.6pt}%

\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{20mm}{*}%
\setulmarginsandblock{30mm}{20mm}{*}%
\setheadfoot{\baselineskip}{2\baselineskip}
\setheaderspaces{20.0mm}{*}{*}%
\setmarginnotes{2.0mm}{16mm}{5.0mm}%
\setcolsepandrule{3.5mm}{0.15mm}
\setfootins{\bigskipamount}{\bigskipamount}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{committee}

\newcommand{\member}[2]{\stepcounter{committee}\csgdef{member\thecommittee}{#1}
\csgdef{institute\thecommittee}{#2}}


\title{Approval sheet: an example for the LaTeX}
\author{Alexsandro Lucena Mota}
\date{2020}


\member{Prof.~MA. Sir Isaac Newton}{Trinity College -- University of Cambridge}

\member{Prof.~PhD. Albert Einstein}{Institute for Advanced Study (IAS)}

\member{Prof. PhD. Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac}{Florida State University}

\member{Prof. PhD. Richard Phillips Feynman}{California Institute of Technology -- Caltech}

\member{Prof. PhD. Murray Gell-Mann}{California Institute of Technology -- Caltech}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        {\large \theauthor\par}
        
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        
        {\Large
            \begin{OnehalfSpace}%
                \bfseries\thetitle\par%
            \end{OnehalfSpace}%
    }

    \vspace{0.0cm}
    
    \end{center}
    \begin{flushright}%
        \begin{minipage}{0.55\textwidth}%
            \begin{SingleSpacing}%     
                {\small Doctoral thesis presented at Postgraduate 
                Program in Physics of the Universidade Federal do 
                Maranhão as prerequisite to obtain the Doctoral 
                degree.}\par
            
                {\small {\bfseries Research line:} Topological 
                field theory with Lorentz symmetry breaking.}\par%
            \end{SingleSpacing}%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{flushright}

    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    Approval in: \rule[0.0cm]{3cm}{0.04cm}~ 
    \rule[0.0cm]{1cm}{0.04cm},~\thedate.\par
    
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    
    \begin{center}
        
        {\Large Examining  Committee}\par%
        
        \vspace{\baselineskip}  
        
        \begin{SingleSpacing}
            \foreach \x in {1,...,\value{committee}}{  
            \rule{12cm}{0.04cm}\par%
            \csuse{member\x}\par%
            \csuse{institute\x}\par
                  
            \vspace{1.9\baselineskip}
            }
        \end{SingleSpacing}
    \end{center}
    
\end{document}
```